# How can I recursively delete folder with numerical names using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory

I have scripts which deletes folders based on their modified dates. 
Can someone help me to delete if folder name contains only numeric in it?

```
$locations=import-csv "C:\Temp\Scripts\AgeOffDirsGeneral.csv"

foreach ($location in $locations)
{

    $Source=$location.Source

    Get-ChildItem  $source  |Where-Object  {$_.psiscontainer}  | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item  -Recurse  -Force $_.FullName}

}
```

Comment: What PowerShell version do you use? Add to your where `-and $_.Name -match '^\d+$'`

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.15063.786

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix this using `-like` tag.

```
$locations=import-csv "C:\Temp\Scripts\AgeOffDirsGeneral.csv"
foreach ($location in $locations)
{
    $Source=$location.Source
    Get-ChildItem  $source  | Where-Object {  $_.psiscontainer -and $_.Name -like '*[0-9]*' } | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item  -Recurse  -Force $_.FullName}
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your requirement was `to delete if folder name contains only numeric in it` your like passes any name containing at least one digit among any other chars.

Answer (score 0):

Remove-Item accepts piped input, so no ForEach neccessary.
If the output looks OK remove the `-WhatIf`

```
locations=import-csv "C:\Temp\Scripts\AgeOffDirsGeneral.csv"

foreach ($location in $locations){

    $Source=$location.Source

    Get-ChildItem  $source -Dir -Recurse|
      Where-Object  { $_.Name -match '^\d+$'}  | 
        Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
}
```

BTW the intermediate variable $source could be avoided directly inserting $location.Source